# unable to delete slide in swiper carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, swiper.js

On creating the carousel, swiperjs creates duplicates of image slides. I want to delete a slide/image on clicking button for which I wrote delete function.

However, the problem is its not deleting duplicate slide created by swiperjs.

**[Here is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PbhM8JY2snA5egviAV0s?p=preview)**

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="dropBox" class="mybox col-lg-12" ondragover="{ondragOver}" ondrop="{showImages}">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slides -->
                <span class="swiper-slide" each="{option, choice in data.images}">
                    <img class='thumbnail' src="{option.imageUrl}" title='preview image'/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var activeIndex = '';
//initializer function in riotjs
self.on('updated', function(){
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
//    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerGroup: 3,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
//    initialSlide: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
})

function deleteImage(e){
    self.data.images.splice(0, 1);
    mySwiper.removeSlide(0);

    // NONE OF THE BELOW DELETES A SLIDE PROPERLY
    //   mySwiper.removeSlide(mySwiper.snapIndex);
    //   mySwiper.removeSlide(0);
    //   mySwiper.removeSlide(mySwiper.clickedIndex);
    //   mySwiper.removeSlide(mySwiper.clickedSlide);
    //   mySwiper.removeSlide(mySwiper.activeIndex);
    //   mySwiper.removeSlide(mySwiper.realIndex);
    //   self.update();
    console.log("self.data.images after delete==", self.data.images);
}
```

How do I get hold of duplicate slide index and real slide index so that I can delete the slide?

Comment: So you are saying the removeSlide-method does not work? I have hard time believing that is the case, it works fine in my test https://jsfiddle.net/a4225adq/ Can you create [mcve] that showcases the problem?

Comment: @Esko your fiddle has only one image. Try with group of image in carousel and delete a specific out of group of images which might reproduce the issue

Comment: @Esko using `slidesPerView: 3,` created duplicate slides

Comment: @Esko added plunkr(verifiable example) to question

Comment: How is that verifiable example, you are not even using swiper in that example? We need to see an example, where you use the removeSlide but it does not work as documented. I don't believe this is the case as my fiddle shows.

Comment: @Esko check it properly. I am using swiper only. check other pages in the plunkr on the left side-bar, you will find it. I think you misunderstood the issue. `removeSlide()` is not working when you have group of images that slide together. I know that removing single slide works but the problem is with group of slides and when you try to remove one slide out of the group